# Download html with encoding utf-8 vs iso-8859-1

Tags: c#, encoding, utf-8, webclient, iso-8859-1

Can I download a webpage with `charset=iso-8859-1`, and download it with `encoding=utf-8`?
Will it download correctly?

Can I always download with utf-8 encoding for all encodings in the web?

**My code:**

Html page in the web:

```
<html debug="true">
<head/>
<body>
<%@LANGUAGE="JAVASCRIPT" CODEPAGE="1252"%>
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<meta name="robots" content="noindex"/>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1"/>
............
```

Func:

```
void download() {
        WebClient client = new WebClient();
        client.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
        client.DownloadDataCompleted += new DownloadDataCompletedEventHandler(client_DownloadDataCompleted);
        worker.ReportProgress(i);
        client.DownloadDataAsync(new Uri(link), i);
}
void client_DownloadDataCompleted(object sender, DownloadDataCompletedEventArgs e) {
   Encoding enc = Encoding.UTF8;
   string myString = enc.GetString(e.Result);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this doesn’t work. The [documentation of `WebClient.Encoding`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.encoding.aspx) clearly says:

> When a string is downloaded using the DownloadString or DownloadStringAsync methods, WebClient uses the Encoding returned by this to convert the downloaded Byte array into a string.

And why should it work? Your web page has an encoding different from UTF-8. Why do you *want* to use UTF-8 here? It makes no sense. The document is encoded as ISO 8859-1, consequently this is the encoding you need to use to read it.

Comment: @Chani This is probably the wrong approach. You need a string, not a byte array, right?

Comment: @Chani That won’t work either, for the same reason: you’re just doing the conversion manually that `WebClient.DownloadString` would do automatically. What exactly are you trying to accomplish here? Please *explain* what you want to do in your question.

Comment: I think that it is clear enough. It is work!! but the question is: Correctly??? without fault in the text?

Comment: @Chani It’s pretty simple: if you use the wrong encoding, it won’t work. UTF-8 and ISO 8859-1 just happen to be fairly similar (they’re identical for the basic US English character set). But as soon as the document uses “special chars” (ä, ß, ø, …, €) your code will break down.

Comment: that's the question: if UTF-8 more than ISO 8859-1, so why it will be a problem??

Comment: @Chanipoz Because it isn’t. ISO 8859-1 has characters that differ from UTF-8 (basically, everything after character code 127).